# write a file on local disk from web app

Tags: javascript, php, file

I have created a "web application" for my personal use that I only use with a local server on my computer. It uses HTML / PHP / Javascript technologies.

I would like to be able to write files with this application but it seems that for security reason (that I can understand) you can't write a file from a web application (or you have to provide a "save" button)...

Is there a way in my particular case (local server) to be able to write a file on my computer (or my server as it happens to be the same machine) ?

Comment: PHP has commands that support file saving, or at the very least being able to run 3rd party scripts (e.g. Python) to save files to servers.

Comment: So you've developed a local web interface for your locally hosted web application. In PHP try `file_put_contents('c:\\newfile.txt', 'text goes here!');`. Javascript which runs in your browser CANNOT write files to your local disk; if it could then website viruses would have completely made the internet unusable by now.